# Fullcalender start with current month and next month in view

Tags: javascript, calendar

I have `fullcalendar` and which start from `2015 Jan`, I want to start and show as default with current month and next month.

Please advice - I have below code

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
     theme: true,
     //now:  gotoDate(CurrentDate),//'2015-08-07',
     editable: true,
     aspectRatio: 2.1,
     scrollTime: '00:00',
     selectable: true,
     selectHelper: true,
```

Answer (score 0):

http://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/defaultDate/

Have you tried specifying a defaultDate?

Answer (score 0):

Yes i did try defaultDate already, it wont work

I already have this

defaultView: 'timelineYear',
                            views: {
                                timelineDay: {
                                    buttonText: ':10 slots',
                                    slotDuration: '00:15'
                                },
                                timelineTenDay: {
                                    type: 'timeline',
                                    duration: { days: 10 }
                                }
                            },

and need to view current month and next month